# Apache Poi excel date cell: date filter not applied to xlsx file (Excels text to columns function has to be called)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm struggling with a very specific Apache Poi/Excel problem in Java:

The code below is working like expected but the expected date filter does not show up automatically in Excel. Only if I use excel's text-to-columns function or if I click once in a date cell and press enter, the cell is truly recognized as a date value and the date filter appears

[Picture 1: After the initial excel creation, no date filter is availabe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63ZGA.png)

[Picture 2: As soon as I've clicked in a date cell and pressed enter, the value is right aligned and the date filter is automatically applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQV0Q.png)

I have tried it by applying date CellStyle like shown below and I've tried it too by applying the date format directly to the excel template used for Apache Poi.

```
//handling the date format
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"));
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMAN);

....
//loop through content
//apply value with cellStyle
cell.setCellValue(dateFormat.format(obj));
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

I've tried different methods (like numeric date values for excel, removing cell style from the template, removing cell style from the java code...) but I always end up with the same result:

Values are correct, cell style of excel is correct, but written values are not detected as dates in the first step

Any ideas? I did not found on how to invoke "text-to-columns" with Apache Poi.
If there is no way to do it, I'll have to write VBA code to invoke "text-to-columns" on Excel startup.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your `cell.setCellValue(dateFormat.format(obj))` sets cell value as `String`. You need using one of the `Cell.setCellValue` methods having a date as parameter: `setCellValue(java.util.Calendar value)` or `setCellValue(java.util.Date value)` or `setCellValue(java.time.LocalDate value)` or `setCellValue(java.time.LocalDateTime value)`.

Comment: Thank you @AxelRichter. Your answer was right and I was able to make it work that easily. As a newbie I'm not allowed to accept/upvote your answer - sorry